# WPF Viewbox only shrink if I shrink the window horizontally

Tags: wpf, resize, viewbox

I have a grid in a Viewbox. If shrink the width of my window the grid getting smaller.. but if I shrink the height, nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds Like the parent container is the problem! I have solved this changing the parent container to Grid (from the default StackPanel in for instance ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate).

Lets see the complete xaml!

Comment: I didn't set any width or height?

Comment: You can also try and use DockPanel with LastChildFill set to True: <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"> If the ViewBox is in the last child, it should scale in the height as well as width!